# Замена строки символов в переменной java

Tags: android, replace

Хочу заменить текст в переменной.

Сам текст берётся JSON'ом и в нём были лишние пробелы и html символы.

От них вроде как избавился этой строкой (это строковая переменная),

```
s.replaceAll("\\<.*?>", "").replaceAll("&nbsp;", "").trim();
```

но есть вот такой блок символов

> {youtube}разный набор символов{/youtube}

Какой командой можно заменить набор символов, начинающийся с " {youtube " и заканчивающийся " youtube} " ?

(Содержимое между этими блоками всегда меняется, поэтому я не могу изменять его, а хотелось бы его обрезать)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так:

```
"{youtube}разный набор символов{/youtube}".replaceAll("\\{youtube\\}[^\\{]*\\{\\/youtube\\}","выпилено");
```

Comment: А можете объяснить, как работают символы в строке? когда я добавляю строку, она почему-то пустоту возвращает, хотя этот блок ютуба вообще в конце текста стоит    

`m.content = item.optString("content").replaceAll("\\<.*?>","").replaceAll("&nbsp;", "").replaceAll("\\{youtube\\}[^\\{]*\\{\\tube}","выпилено").trim();`

Comment: Поправил экранирование последней фигурной скобки. А вы неверно скопировали регулярку.

Comment: Теперь помогло =)

Answer (score 2):

Так попробуйте:

```
String text = "132 {youtube}раолов{/youtube} my ggfd 543 {youtube}мволов{/youtube} jhghjg";
        int start = text.indexOf("{youtube}");
        int end = text.indexOf("{/youtube}");
        String subString = text.substring(start, end + 10);
        text = text.replace(subString, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так.

```
String myTxt = "ваш текст";
StringBuilder myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(myTxt);
myStringBuilder.replace(myTxt.indexOf("{youtube}")+9,
    myTxt.indexOf("{/youtube}"),"нужный текст");
myTxt = myStringBuilder.toString();
```

+9 - это размер `String` "{youtube}". Поэкспериментируйте, какой точно результат вам нужен - чтобы сам {youtube} заменялся или нет?